# How do I exclude some code on posts and pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a feature box on my header.php file, because of this the feature box gets displayed in every page and post page as well. What code do I need to keep this feature box only in the homepage and no place else?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) function:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    // Show the feature box
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```